# How to hide slider handle from specific sliders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm wondering if there's a method to hide id or class specific slider handles?

```
<label for="my-slider-id">Test</label>
<input type="range" class="my-slider-class" id="my-slider-id" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
```

For example, I'm aware that this code hides handles for all sliders.

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').hide();
```

And these codes do absolutely nothing:

```
$('ui-slider-handle.my-slider-class').hide();

$('ui-slider-handle#my-slider-id').hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it through jQuery only, like this:

```
$('#my-slider-id').next().find('.ui-slider-handle').hide();
```

Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/T2zde/

Comment: or with css: #slider-id > .ui-slider-handle { display:none; }