# Remove and Change noUIslider handle

Tags: javascript, html, nouislider

I'm trying to hide the handle (the bar that allows you to drag and the slider.

[I'm currently using the nouislider javascript library](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and now trying to get rid of it.

So far I've tried the following:

```
Html: 
<div class = 'slider' id='sliderinfo'> </div>
Javascript:
var slider = document.getElementById('sliderinfo');
var hider = slider.getElementsByClassName('.noUi-handle');
hider.remove();
//Separate way of hding
```

as well as the following somewhat related [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770162/how-to-hide-slider-handle-from-specific-sliders) including [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812263/customize-nouislider-handle-with-text-and-shape-into-circle) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839294/custom-image-handle-for-nouislider) and I've had no response as to hiding or removing the handle for the slider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the bottom of one of the previously accepted answers, although it wasn't clear to me.

```
.noUi-handle { display:none; }
```